# Wildcard subdomain redirect with mod_rewrite and mod_proxy times out

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm having trouble with a redirect I'm doing for a website.
The system I'm making calls for users to have their own address as in

`http://user1.domain.com/`
with possible filenames as in

`http://user1.domain.com/file.html`

This is redirected to `http://www.domain.com/php?user=user1&file=file.html`

This part works fine, as I've already set up a wildcard redirect via cpanel;
`*.domain.com` redirects to `www.domain.com/users/`. (I'm unable to redirect to the root, as there is another system with a heavy .htaccess which already runs there, and I've tried, but it seem to be hijacking what I'm trying to do and redirect me to index.php).
In the `users` folder is where my .htaccess-file resides.

This is written as such

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.html)?$ http://www.domain.com/php?user=%1&file=$1 [P]
```

Problem is though, that if I use the [P] flag on the last rule, the server just times out, and the request ends.
If I use the [L] flag, the rewrite works as intended, but the URL is redirected to `www.domain.com/php?user=user1&file=file.html`

What I want is for the user to see
`user1.domain.com/file.html`

while the content from
`www.domain.com/php?user=user1&file=file.html` is displayed.

From what I (think I) can tell, the mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http is enabled, otherwise the [P] flag would generate a 500 error.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, and I cannot seem to figure it out.
I do not have access to httpd.conf, or other server configurations, as this is on a shared hosting service.

Please help.

Comment: If your wildcard subdomains are pointing to your document root, then surely you don't need to use `P`? Will a simple `^(.*)(.html)?$ /php?user=%1&file=$1 [L]` not do the trick? (Genuine question, because I've never actually tried it; but it does make logical sense to me.)

Comment: I'd also recommend changing `.*` to `.+` - that's actually quite important.

Comment: Thanks for answers

Comment: I've tried different uses of greedy/non-greedy regex, and it makes no difference. Regarding the wildcard subdomain; I agree with your logic, and by all accounts, it should not have to redirect. I know the way I've done it is probably not optimal, but because the file I'm redirecting to is running on top of a framework's files, I can't simply set it to redirect to the specified folder where the file resides. (Prestashop framework), I have to redirect to index.php for the module to run. Because of this, it always redirects to www.